# Audio will not play on Android using phonegap, but works fine on iOS

Tags: android, html, cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins

**It works fine on iOS.**

I have looked many answers including these 2:

[Play sound on Phonegap app for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515699/play-sound-on-phonegap-app-for-android)

[HTML5 audio not playing in PhoneGap App (Possible to use Media?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638741/html5-audio-not-playing-in-phonegap-app-possible-to-use-media)

I have tried all of the solutions:

- Changing the path to `/android_asset/www/` for Android
- Using .ogg files
- Pre load the audio with a play() / pause().
- Using the Media plugin provided by Cordova/Phonegap

Here is my current code:

```
if(device.platform === "Android")   //DIFFERENT PATH FOR ANDROID
{
    url = "/android_asset/www/sound.ogg";
}else{
    url = "sound.mp3";
}
alert(url);
sound = new Media(url);
sound.play();
```

Anyone have an ideas?? It feels like I have been going round in circles

Comment: I faced the same issue and still no solution.

Comment: Hmmmm, this is worrying! There are so many different answers all over Stackoverflow, but none seem to work :/

Comment: Did you try it on an emulator or real device? 
Try to press volume hardware key, does it crash your app?

Comment: I am trying it on a nexus 5

Comment: Pressing the volume button did work!!!! Why does it automatically mute it????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working!!

I first initialising the audio file by finding the full Android path using @Sarim Sidd help above and then preloading the audio file:

```
//INITIALISE SOUND
if(device.platform === "Android")   //DIFFERENT PATH FOR ANDROID
{
    //navigator.notification.beep(1);
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substr( path, path.length - 10 ); //strip off index.html
    url = 'file://'+path+"sound.ogg";
}else{
    url = "sound.mp3";
}
//sound = new Media(url);
sound = new Media(url);
sound.play();
sound.pause();
```

Then when to play the audio I forced the volume to full (1.0) before calling the play method. For some reason I noticed the audio kept reseting to mute each time I started the app:

```
//PLAY BELL SOUND THROUGH APP
sound.setVolume(1.0);
sound.play();
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar and this solution worked for me
Get complete path of your application using `window.location.pathname`, this way you dont need to worry about device type, it will give you the complete path including `index.html` and by using the below function simply strip off `index.html` from the string and append your media file.

```
function getPhoneGapPath() {

var path = window.location.pathname;
path = path.substr( path, path.length - 10 ); //strip off index.html
return 'file://' + path;

};
```

And then

```
url = getPhoneGapPath()+'sound.ogg';  //OR MP3 

alert(url);
sound = new Media(url);
sound.play();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Still no luck! The URL outputs `file:///android_asset/www/sound.ogg`