# adobe animate sounds not working on phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio, phonegap

I have build a html5 android app with Adobe animate cc, every thing work perfectly on browser, but when I build using phoneGap I lose sounds.

Kindly find attached codes
This is index.js

```
 (function (lib, img, cjs, ss, an) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
lib.webFontTxtInst = {}; 
var loadedTypekitCount = 0;
var loadedGoogleCount = 0;
var gFontsUpdateCacheList = [];
var tFontsUpdateCacheList = [];
lib.ssMetadata = [
        {name:"index_atlas_", frames: [[0,0,502,800],[0,802,100,111]]}
];



lib.updateListCache = function (cacheList) {        
    for(var i = 0; i < cacheList.length; i++) {     
        if(cacheList[i].cacheCanvas)        
            cacheList[i].updateCache();     
    }       
};      

lib.addElementsToCache = function (textInst, cacheList) {       
    var cur = textInst;     
    while(cur != exportRoot) {      
        if(cacheList.indexOf(cur) != -1)        
            break;      
        cur = cur.parent;       
    }       
    if(cur != exportRoot) {     
        var cur2 = textInst;        
        var index = cacheList.indexOf(cur);     
        while(cur2 != cur) {        
            cacheList.splice(index, 0, cur2);       
            cur2 = cur2.parent;     
            index++;        
        }       
    }       
    else {      
        cur = textInst;     
        while(cur != exportRoot) {      
            cacheList.push(cur);        
            cur = cur.parent;       
        }       
    }       
};      

lib.gfontAvailable = function(family, totalGoogleCount) {       
    lib.properties.webfonts[family] = true;     
    var txtInst = lib.webFontTxtInst && lib.webFontTxtInst[family] || [];       
    for(var f = 0; f < txtInst.length; ++f)     
        lib.addElementsToCache(txtInst[f], gFontsUpdateCacheList);      

    loadedGoogleCount++;        
    if(loadedGoogleCount == totalGoogleCount) {     
        lib.updateListCache(gFontsUpdateCacheList);     
    }       
};      

lib.tfontAvailable = function(family, totalTypekitCount) {      
    lib.properties.webfonts[family] = true;     
    var txtInst = lib.webFontTxtInst && lib.webFontTxtInst[family] || [];       
    for(var f = 0; f < txtInst.length; ++f)     
        lib.addElementsToCache(txtInst[f], tFontsUpdateCacheList);      

    loadedTypekitCount++;       
    if(loadedTypekitCount == totalTypekitCount) {       
        lib.updateListCache(tFontsUpdateCacheList);     
    }       
};
// symbols:



(lib.BabykidsLearningStudyMusicalSoundCellPhoneChildrenEducationalToysMobilePhonesLearningToy = function() {
    this.spriteSheet = ss["index_atlas_"];
    this.gotoAndStop(0);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.lightorange = function() {
    this.spriteSheet = ss["index_atlas_"];
    this.gotoAndStop(1);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();
// helper functions:

function mc_symbol_clone() {
    var clone = this._cloneProps(new this.constructor(this.mode, this.startPosition, this.loop));
    clone.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame);
    clone.paused = this.paused;
    clone.framerate = this.framerate;
    return clone;
}

function getMCSymbolPrototype(symbol, nominalBounds, frameBounds) {
    var prototype = cjs.extend(symbol, cjs.MovieClip);
    prototype.clone = mc_symbol_clone;
    prototype.nominalBounds = nominalBounds;
    prototype.frameBounds = frameBounds;
    return prototype;
    }


(lib.Symbol6 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 1
    this.instance = new lib.lightorange();
    this.instance.parent = this;

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol6, new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,100,111), null);


(lib.Symbol5 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 1
    this.instance = new lib.lightorange();
    this.instance.parent = this;

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol5, new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,100,111), null);


(lib.Symbol4 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 1
    this.instance = new lib.lightorange();
    this.instance.parent = this;

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol4, new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,100,111), null);


(lib.Symbol1 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_2 = function() {
        playSound("Alef");
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).wait(2).call(this.frame_2).wait(2));

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#FF0000").s().p("Ah/XBMAAAgjrID3AAMAAAAjrgAj1u2IAAiGIBoAAIg0g7IgXhaQABhhBDhEQBLhKBuAAIBxAPQAXAAAdAPIAACOIgIAAIidgeIhgAWIgeBLQAABLBEAeQBDAsBYAAIBxAAIAACGg");
    this.shape.setTransform(11.3,67.3,0.457,0.457);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#FF0000").s().p("Ah/XBMAAAgjrID3AAMAAAAjrgAj1u2IAAiGIBoAAIg0g7IgXhaQABhhBDhEQBLhKBuAAIBxAPQAXAAAdAPIAACOIgIAAIidgeIhgAWIgeBLQAABLBEAeQBDAsBYAAIBxAAIAACGg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(11.3,67.3,0.457,0.457);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape,p:{scaleX:0.457,scaleY:0.457,x:11.3,y:67.3}}]}).to({state:[{t:this.shape,p:{scaleX:0.457,scaleY:0.457,x:11.3,y:67.3}}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape,p:{scaleX:0.902,scaleY:0.902,x:-98.5,y:-195.7}}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.shape,p:{scaleX:0.457,scaleY:0.457,x:11.3,y:67.3}}]},1).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,22.6,134.6);


(lib.button_ta2 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_2 = function() {
        playSound("ta2");
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).wait(2).call(this.frame_2).wait(2));

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#FF0000").s().p("AgxLXQiFgDiCgTQiigXiVg0QiZgzhzhuQhbhYgrhzQgyiFAAiQQAAh8Aah3IAIgtID2AAIgVDFQgIBZASBWQARBWA4BFQBABOBbAvQBIAlBRARIAqAFQDAAXC9gBQDMgBDMgdQAmgDAmgMQBdgeBOg3QAkgaAjgjQBEhGAUhgQAQhUgGhWQgHhYgThTIgHgjID3AAQAUBqANBfQALBUgIBOQgKBugpBnQgUAyghAvIg0BBQguAyg4AnQg3Amg1AdQg8Ahg+AVQiOAriSASQh3AOh0ADgABvn9IAAjZIDZAAIAADZgAlwn9IAAjZIDZAAIAADZg");
    this.shape.setTransform(107.6,72.7);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#FF0000").s().p("AgxLXQiFgDiCgTQiigXiVg0QiZgzhzhuQhbhYgrhzQgyiFAAiQQAAh8Aah3IAIgtID2AAIgVDFQgIBZASBWQARBWA4BFQBABOBbAvQBIAlBRARIAqAFQDAAXC9gBQDMgBDMgdQAmgDAmgMQBdgeBOg3QAkgaAjgjQBEhGAUhgQAQhUgGhWQgHhYgThTIgHgjID3AAQAUBqANBfQALBUgIBOQgKBugpBnQgUAyghAvIg0BBQguAyg4AnQg3Amg1AdQg8Ahg+AVQiOAriSASQh3AOh0ADgABvn9IAAjZIDZAAIAADZgAlwn9IAAjZIDZAAIAADZg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(107.6,72.7);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape,p:{scaleX:1,scaleY:1,x:107.6,y:72.7}}]}).to({state:[{t:this.shape,p:{scaleX:1,scaleY:1,x:107.6,y:72.7}}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape,p:{scaleX:2.341,scaleY:2.341,x:308.3,y:-570.2}}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.shape,p:{scaleX:1,scaleY:1,x:107.6,y:72.7}}]},1).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,215.1,145.5);


(lib.button_ba2 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_2 = function() {
        playSound("ba2");
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).wait(2).call(this.frame_2).wait(2));

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#FF0000").s().p("AhrLjIAAjYIDYAAIAADYgAgxEgQiFgCiCgVQiegViZg1QiZgyhzhvQhahWgsh1QgyiDAAiSQAAh8Aah4IAIgsID2AAIgVDEQgIBbASBWQARBWA4BFQBABPBbAtQBKAnBPAQIAqAFQDAAYC9gCQDMgCDMgcQAmgDAmgMQBbgdBQg4QAngbAggiQBEhGAUhhQAQhTgGhYQgHhXgThTIgHgjID3AAQAUBqANBfQALBVgIBOQgKBugpBnQgUA0ghAtIg0BAQguAyg4AnQgyAkg6AfQg5AghBAWQiKAqiWATQhwAOh7ADg");
    this.shape.setTransform(107.6,73.9);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#FF0000").s().p("AhrLjIAAjYIDYAAIAADYgAgxEgQiFgCiCgVQiegViZg1QiZgyhzhvQhahWgsh1QgyiDAAiSQAAh8Aah4IAIgsID2AAIgVDEQgIBbASBWQARBWA4BFQBABPBbAtQBKAnBPAQIAqAFQDAAYC9gCQDMgCDMgcQAmgDAmgMQBbgdBQg4QAngbAggiQBEhGAUhhQAQhTgGhYQgHhXgThTIgHgjID3AAQAUBqANBfQALBVgIBOQgKBugpBnQgUA0ghAtIg0BAQguAyg4AnQgyAkg6AfQg5AghBAWQiKAqiWATQhwAOh7ADg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(107.6,73.9);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape,p:{scaleX:1,scaleY:1,x:107.6,y:73.9}}]}).to({state:[{t:this.shape,p:{scaleX:1,scaleY:1,x:107.6,y:73.9}}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape,p:{scaleX:2.035,scaleY:2.035,x:21.2,y:-640}}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.shape,p:{scaleX:1,scaleY:1,x:107.6,y:73.9}}]},1).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,215.1,147.8);


(lib.Symbol2 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 2
    this.instance = new lib.lightorange();
    this.instance.parent = this;
    this.instance.setTransform(-1,0);
    this.instance._off = true;

    this.instance_1 = new lib.Symbol6();
    this.instance_1.parent = this;
    this.instance_1.setTransform(49,55.5,1,1,0,0,0,50,55.5);
    this.instance_1.filters = [new cjs.ColorFilter(0, 0, 0, 1, 255, 255, 255, 0)];
    this.instance_1.cache(-2,-2,104,115);

    this.instance_2 = new lib.Symbol4();
    this.instance_2.parent = this;
    this.instance_2.setTransform(49,55.5,1,1,0,0,0,50,55.5);
    this.instance_2.filters = [new cjs.ColorFilter(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 127.5, 127.5, 0, 0)];
    this.instance_2.cache(-2,-2,104,115);

    this.instance_3 = new lib.Symbol5();
    this.instance_3.parent = this;
    this.instance_3.setTransform(49,55.5,1,1,0,0,0,50,55.5);
    this.instance_3.filters = [new cjs.ColorFilter(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 25.5, 127.5, 51, 0)];
    this.instance_3.cache(-2,-2,104,115);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[]}).to({state:[{t:this.instance}]},1).to({state:[]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_1}]},1).to({state:[]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance}]},1).to({state:[]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_2}]},1).to({state:[]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance}]},1).to({state:[]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance}]},1).to({state:[]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_3}]},1).to({state:[]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance}]},1).wait(1));
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1).to({_off:false},0).to({_off:true},1).wait(3).to({_off:false},0).to({_off:true},1).wait(3).to({_off:false},0).to({_off:true},1).wait(1).to({_off:false},0).to({_off:true},1).wait(3).to({_off:false},0).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = null;


(lib.FL = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_0 = function() {
        /* Stop at This Frame
        The  timeline will stop/pause at the frame where you insert this code.
        Can also be used to stop/pause the timeline of movieclips.
        */

        this.stop();
    }
    this.frame_19 = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop(0);
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).call(this.frame_0).wait(19).call(this.frame_19).wait(1));

    // Layer 3
    this.instance = new lib.Symbol2();
    this.instance.parent = this;
    this.instance.setTransform(-93,-757.5,1,1,0,0,0,50,55.5);
    this.instance._off = true;

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1).to({_off:false},0).wait(19));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = null;


// stage content:
(lib.index = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_0 = function() {
        this.stop();

        this.button_alef.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_3.bind(this));
        function fl_MouseClickHandler_3()
        {
            this.FL_MC.play();
        }

        this.button_ba2.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_3.bind(this));
        function fl_MouseClickHandler_3()
        {
            this.FL_MC.play();
        }


        this.button_ta2.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_3.bind(this));
        function fl_MouseClickHandler_3()
        {
            this.FL_MC.play();
        }
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).call(this.frame_0).wait(1));

    // ت
    this.button_ta2 = new lib.button_ta2();
    this.button_ta2.parent = this;
    this.button_ta2.setTransform(226.8,545.8,0.325,0.325,0,0,0,107.9,72.9);
    new cjs.ButtonHelper(this.button_ta2, 0, 1, 2, false, new lib.button_ta2(), 3);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.button_ta2).wait(1));

    // ب
    this.button_ba2 = new lib.button_ba2();
    this.button_ba2.parent = this;
    this.button_ba2.setTransform(313.9,558.8,0.325,0.325,0,0,0,107.8,74.1);
    new cjs.ButtonHelper(this.button_ba2, 0, 1, 2, false, new lib.button_ba2(), 3);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.button_ba2).wait(1));

    // أ
    this.button_alef = new lib.Symbol1();
    this.button_alef.parent = this;
    this.button_alef.setTransform(376.1,528.5,0.805,0.805,0,0,0,11.3,67.3);
    new cjs.ButtonHelper(this.button_alef, 0, 1, 2, false, new lib.Symbol1(), 3);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.button_alef).wait(1));

    // flash light
    this.FL_MC = new lib.FL();
    this.FL_MC.parent = this;
    this.FL_MC.setTransform(603.2,950.1,1,1,0,0,0,34.4,34.4);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.FL_MC).wait(1));

    // BG
    this.instance = new lib.BabykidsLearningStudyMusicalSoundCellPhoneChildrenEducationalToysMobilePhonesLearningToy();
    this.instance.parent = this;
    this.instance.setTransform(49,83);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(349,563,502,800);
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    width: 600,
    height: 960,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    opacity: 1.00,
    webfonts: {},
    manifest: [
        {src:"images/index_atlas_.png", id:"index_atlas_"},
        {src:"sounds/Alef.mp3", id:"Alef"},
        {src:"sounds/ba2.mp3", id:"ba2"},
        {src:"sounds/ta2.mp3", id:"ta2"}
    ],
    preloads: []
};




})(lib = lib||{}, images = images||{}, createjs = createjs||{}, ss = ss||{}, AdobeAn = AdobeAn||{});
var lib, images, createjs, ss, AdobeAn;
```

This is config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>BabyPhone</name>
  <description>
   Arabic BabyPhone
  </description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
     Sameh
  </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
      <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon src="icon.png" />



  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
      <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
      <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>


  <!--Android Preferences-->

<preference name="KeepRunning" value="false"/> 

<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="10000"/>

<preference name="SplashScreen" value="mySplash"/>

<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>

<preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true"/>

<preference name="LoadingDialog" value="My Title,My Message"/>

<preference name="LoadingPageDialog" value="My Title,My Message"/>

<preference name="ErrorUrl" value="myErrorPage.html"/>

<preference name="ShowTitle" value="true"/>

<preference name="LogLevel" value="VERBOSE"/>

<preference name="SetFullscreen" value="false"/>

<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop"/>

<splash src="splash_screens/mdpi.png" platform="Android" width="300" height="300" density="mdpi"> </splash>

</widget>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Audio will not play on Android using phonegap, but works fine on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259395/audio-will-not-play-on-android-using-phonegap-but-works-fine-on-ios)