# Filepath to local sound in PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to access sound files stored on the device for the first time. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438822/playing-local-sound-in-phonegap) popular post using the following with little success

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="/android_asset/www/audio/definition.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <source src="/android_asset/www/audio/definition.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I do confess that I'm new to this so apologies if i'm missing something blindingly obvious ... but what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Using phonegap media plugin should solve the problem. 
Please check the answer given by @QuickFix in this link [HTML5 audio not playing in PhoneGap App (Possible to use Media?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638741/html5-audio-not-playing-in-phonegap-app-possible-to-use-media)