# Play sound on Phonegap app for Android

Tags: android, cordova

I try to play an mp3 file. This works if I change the path to the file on my local webserver, but if I run this on an Android device the sound is not played and no error is shown.

I am pretty shure that the mp3 file is not found, but I still don't know how to fix it.

This is the **Html**

```
  <body>

        <audio id="successSound" src="/android_asset/www/sound/successSound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" ></audio>
           <audio id="errorSound" src="/android_asset/www/sound/errorSound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" ></audio>
<!-- some more UI -->
  </body>
```

This is the **Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('errorSound').play();
```

The is the **file structure**

```
phonyapp
`-- www
    `-- index.html
        |-- sound
        |   |-- errorSound.mp3
        |   `-- successSound.mp3
        |-- res
        `-- spec
```

**Edit 1**

I tried

```
<audio id="successSound" src="sound/successSound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" ></audio>
```

This worked in chrome on my local webserver but not on Android.

I tried

```
<audio id="successSound" src="http://html5multimedia.com/media/sayHello.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" ></audio>
```

This worked, but I need to get local files playing

Comment: Searching google for cordova solution gets here. See simple answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54943127/984471

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The play method which the HTML5 API provides is useful for playing media files available on the web. Phonegap provides the media plugin to play local media files. I checked out your code and played the sound successfully by making the following changes. Please check at your end.

1.Add the following line to config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
```

2.Replace the lines in index.html

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('successSound').play()">Play successSound local</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('errorSound').play()">Play errorSound local</button>
```

with these lines

```
<button onclick="playAudio('successSound')">Play successSound local</button>
<button onclick="playAudio('errorSound')">Play errorSoundlocal</button>
```

3.Add the following function to js/index.js

```
function playAudio(id) {
    var audioElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var url = audioElement.getAttribute('src');
    var my_media = new Media(url,
            // success callback
             function () { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success"); },
            // error callback
             function (err) { console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err); }
    );
           // Play audio
    my_media.play();
}
```

Comment: Works for me too using the Media object.

Comment: Your solution worked but I had to give absolute path to audio file. Thanks

Comment: Worked, had to do the same as netchi.  This is only an issue (not using HTML5 audio) < Android 5.

Comment: When printing err we will get [object object]. Better to do JSON.stringify(err)

Answer (score 4):

Use this code

```
  <body>

    <audio id="successSound" src="file:///android_asset/www/sound/successSound.mp3"      type="audio/mpeg" ></audio>
       <audio id="errorSound" src="file///android_asset/www/sound/errorSound.mp3"   type="audio/mpeg" ></audio>
<!-- some more UI -->
 </body>
```

Comment: what about iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the `/android_asset/www/` part in your code? Your app acts like a website and it thinks its root is the www folder itself.

Edit:
I'll edit comment. Code not showing somehow.

Comment: Try this: <audio controls><source src="....mp3" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using local files, try to reference them with `src="file:///yourpath/sayHello.mp3"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally got it working, with me the problem lied with the scope of my media variable. I got it working as follows:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";
     var media;
     document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    media = new Media("/android_asset/www/sounds/wat is je wens.mp3", null, function (e) {
    alert('Media Error');
    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    });

    alert('deviceready')
};
function onStart() {
    media.play();
    alert('yay')

}
};
```

Essentially I made sure that the scope of my media variable was sort of global by declaring it outside of onDeviceReady, but that Media wasn't called before the deviceready event.

Answer (score 0):

```
`` // Audio player
        //
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;
        // Play audio
        //
        function playAudio(src) {
            // Create Media object from src
            my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

            // Play audio
            my_media.play();

            // Update my_media position every second
            if (mediaTimer == null) {
                mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                    // get my_media position
                    my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                        // success callback
                        function(position) {
                            if (position > -1) {
                                setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                            }
                        },
                        // error callback
                        function(e) {
                            console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                            setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                        }
                    );
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
        // onSuccess Callback
        //
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }
function stopAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.stop();
            }
            clearInterval(mediaTimer);
            mediaTimer = null;
        }
        // onError Callback
        //
        function onError(error) {
        }
        // Set audio position
        //
        function setAudioPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
        }
```