# Ionic/Cordova app plays sound in emulator but not on Android device

Tags: android, cordova, audio, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and Cordova, so I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but my problem is a packaged APK does not play sounds on an Android device.  I can get the sound to play in the Ripple emulator just fine with the following code:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.playStartBell = function () {
            var media = new Media('media/startBell.mp3', function () {
                console.log('good');
            }, function (err) {
                console.log('bad: ', err);
            });
            media.play();
        },
            $scope.playStopBell = function () {
            var media = new Media('media/stopBell.mp3', function () {
                console.log('good');
            }, function (err) {
                console.log('bad: ', err);
            });
            media.play();
        }
    }])
```

I've used Cordova to install the media plugin: `$cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media`

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515699/play-sound-on-phonegap-app-for-android), a value needs to be added to the config.xml, but I'm not sure how to do it properly for Ionic/Cordova.

Comment: You may want to consider creating the Media objects outside those functions so you can cache them and not re-create them on every execution.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondCamden Can you point me in the right direction for your recommendation?  I was thinking of moving this code to a service that would be injected where needed.  This code is just me getting my hands dirty in the framework.

Comment: I wasn't even thinking of a service, just literally moving the var x = new Media() lines to the beginning of the controller then access x (use a better name ;) in the functions.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that you have specify path starting with the /android_asset/www prefix like so:

> /android_asset/www/

So changing my code to the following worked.  Note you'll want to detect what device you're running on to determine the appropriate location.

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        ///android_asset/www/
        $scope.playStartBell = function () {
            var media = new Media('/android_asset/www/media/startBell.mp3', function () {
                console.log('good');
            }, function (err) {
                console.log('bad: ', err);
            });
            media.play();
        },
            $scope.playStopBell = function () {
            var media = new Media('/android_asset/www/media/stopBell.mp3', function () {
                console.log('good');
            }, function (err) {
                console.log('bad: ', err);
            });
            media.play();
        }
    }])
```