# Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova Media Play Issue

Tags: android, cordova

Issue: Using the media module, I can play back an mp3 just fine in the base Ripple Nexus emulator, but on my android device I do not get any sound.  It doesn't look like it is throwing an error.

Anyone have a similar issue?  I'm pretty new to Cordova.  This was my hello world example.  I spiced it up by downloading the media module and adding this snippet into the index.js file-

```
 var element = document.getElementById("deviceready");
    element.innerHTML = 'Play Message';
    element.className += ' ready';
    element.onclick = function () {

        var media = new Media("images/test.mp3", null, null);
        media.play();

    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  You have to prepend the path /android_asset/www/ to your media URL for android devices I guess.  Would be nice if Cordova took care of that for you.

These post where helpful.

[Ionic/Cordova app plays sound in emulator but not on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924724/ionic-cordova-app-plays-sound-in-emulator-but-not-on-android-device)

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/06/23/Cordova-Media-API-Example/