# playing audio sounds in Cordova application

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using Cordova media plugin for playing audio sound in my mobile application 
I tried many codes but I didn't figure out what I'm doing wrong at the bottom I put two piece of code that I tried them

the first code (js code in a separate file)

```
   var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {


        var myMedia = new Media("../sounds/clapping.mp3");
        myMedia.play();

    }
};

app.initialize();
```

the second code  (js code in a script tag) :

```
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

   var myMedia = null;
    function playAudio() {

    var src = "sounds/clapping.mp3";

    if(myMedia === null) {
    myMedia = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

    function onSuccess() {
    console.log("playAudio Success");
    }

    function onError(error) {
    console.log("playAudio Error: " + error.code);
    }

    }

    myMedia.play();
    }

    document.getElementById("playAudio").addEventListener("click", playAudio);
    });
```

with a button :

```
<button id ="playAudio">PLAY</button>
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Check out this link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Media

Comment: thanks for your  helpful reply 
I tried your code but it doesn't work also .

I was reading a book where I found : "The location where a Cordova application stores the media files packaged with the application
varies across the different mobile device platforms. Android files are located in the
/android_asset folder,"

but when I searched for this file in my project I didn't found it

Comment: The code is posted in the github page are all tried ans tested in device (both iOS and Android) So could you post the error which you encountered while trying this sample in device?

Comment: In my smart phone there is no error message but when I open my app in virtual device I get a pop window saying that there is not file under /android_asset/www/

Comment: In Myproject\platforms\android there is assets file I change
return "/android_asset/www/" + s;
to
return "/assets/www/" + s;

but the sound doesn't work also

Comment: I dont think you can test it on a virtual device. And in device, there got to be some errors in console which you gotta inspect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118192/discussion-between-gandhi-and-taha).

Comment: android_asset refers to project root folder

Comment: thank you for your help 

if(device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") was the source of problem I get an error message saying that device is not defined 

After deleting it the sound worked perfectly also your reply that android_asset is the root folder is so precious

Comment: Have posted the answer for the benefit of other's too. Please accept if it was helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you can find the working sample of cordova app using Media Plugin in the following [github page](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Media).

As mentioned in the sample project's README, you gotta install cordova device plugin as well to check the device platform.

Also to clarify the doubt you mentioned in the comment, `android_asset` refers to the project's root folder.

Answer (score 7):

**Wasted 2 hours on this, sharing it here:**

This should not be this difficult. No full example at: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/

**Simple step by step details:**

1. Put my file in www:

Example at:  `www/audio/button-1.mp3`

2. Install plugin:

   `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media`
3. Copy paste code below:

`

```
  function getFullMediaURL(s) {
    return cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/audio/button-1.mp3'
  }

  function playMP3() {
    let src = getFullMediaURL();
    var myMedia =
      new Media(src,
        function () { },
        function (e) { alert('Media Error: ' + JSON.stringify(e)); }
      );
    myMedia.play();
    myMedia.setVolume('1.0');
  }
```

`

Step 4: Call below where you need play sound:

```
playMP3();
```

Comment: It's an open source project and they have a lot to work on. Add the code using the edit button on the site

Comment: @DaraJava - would you please help add the same to the said website? ty