# cordova android won't play local audio file

Tags: html, cordova, html5-audio

I want to play local audio file using tag audio.

when I put

```
<audio controls preload><source src="http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
```

everything works just fine, but when I put

```
<audio controls preload><source src="/android_asset/www/audio/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
```

it won't play. I tried also to put only src="audio/audio.mp3". Any idea why it doesn't work?
Thanks!

Comment: have you got phonegap installed?

Comment: the audiohandler for cordova was amended just 2 weeks ago. it indicates where local files should be stored . check it out on github https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/src/android/AudioHandler.java

Comment: I found only this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524884/how-can-i-use-html5-audio-tags-to-play-local-mp3s-on-android-using-phonegap

Comment: You can also try using [media plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/doc/index.md) to play audio

Comment: I know but I have to implement also a progress bar.